# MySQL: Update column with TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I have this code that prevents duplicates if column C is equal to a specific value

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER special_unique_test BEFORE INSERT ON myTable 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
       IF NEW.C = 'x' AND EXISTS (
          SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE A = NEW.A AND B = NEW.B AND C = 'x'
       )THEN

          UPDATE myTable SET D = D + 1 WHERE A = NEW.A AND B = NEW.B AND C = 'x';

       END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Everything works except that the update statement isn't executed.

**ADDED**

Tried this in PhpMyAdmin and I got this error:

1442 - Can't update table 'myTable' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

I could go around this by making a separate table for the D column but it would be nice to have it in the same table.

Extra question: How can I make this error show when I insert something from my website using mysqli?

Answer (score 3):

As documented under [Restrictions on Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/stored-program-restrictions.html):

> A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

If you want to increment `D` only in the newly inserted row, you merely need `SET NEW.D = NEW.D + 1;`.  If you wish to increment `D` for every 'colliding' record, you will need to store `D` in some other (related) table.  For example, you *could* store column `D` in a separate table with FK `(A, B, C)` back into `myTable`.

However one can't help but wonder whether there's a better way to achieve your overall goal: what exactly is the *business problem* that you are trying to address with this trigger?  Beware of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: A basic answer to what I want to achieve is that I have a table where you can only add data. I then want to make the combination between 2 columns unique if the 3rd one is equal to a specific value. If the same data is inserted again I want the counter to increase each time.

Comment: @Oskwish: That's the *technical problem* that you're trying to address, not the underlying *business problem*.  Why do you want to do this?  Please read that link explaining the XY problem.